# Button action in CollectionView cell swift

Tags: swift

I have a button in my CollectionViewCell and I added an action to the button but the action does not get triggered. I am currently using the cell independently.

```
class BalanceCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    lazy var toggleBtn: ToggleButton = {
        let view = ToggleButton()
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return view
    }()
    
    lazy var titleLabel: LabelX = {
        let view = LabelX()
        view.text = "My Available Balance"
        view.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)
        return view
    }()
    
    lazy var amountLabel: TextFieldX = {
        let view = TextFieldX()
        view.isSecureTextEntry = true
        view.text = "N000,000.00"
        view.textAlignment = .center
        view.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 26, weight: .medium)
        return view
    }()
    
    private lazy var stackView: StackViewX = {
       let view = StackViewX(arrangedSubviews: [titleLabel, amountLabel])
        view.alignment = .center
        view.axis = .vertical
        view.distribution = .fillProportionally
        view.spacing = 4
        return view
    }()
    
    lazy var bgImageView: ImageViewX = {
        let view = ImageViewX()
        view.backgroundColor = R.color.roundEdgeButtonBgColor()
        return view
    }()
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setupViewHierarchy()
        setupConstraints()
        setupProperties()
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    
    func setupViewHierarchy() {
        addSubview(bgImageView)
        bgImageView.addSubviews([stackView, toggleBtn])
    }
    
    func setupConstraints() {

        bgImageView.fillToSuperview()
        stackView.centerInSuperview()
        toggleBtn.anchor(verticalY: bgImageView.centerYAnchor, horizontalX: nil, paddingX: 0, paddingY: 0, width: 24, height: 24, enableInsets: false)
        toggleBtn.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.leftAnchor, constant: -18).isActive = true
    }
    
    func setupProperties() {
        bgImageView.backgroundColor = .red
        bgImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        layer.cornerRadius = 15
    }
    
    func setup(with title: String, amount: String, bgImageViewColor: UIColor) {
        titleLabel.text = title
        amountLabel.text = amount
        bgImageView.backgroundColor = bgImageViewColor
    }
    
    @objc private func onTapped() {
        self.setSecureMode(self.toggleBtn.isSecure)
    }
    
    private func setSecureMode(_ secure: Bool) {
        amountLabel.isSecureTextEntry = secure
        
        let tempText = amountLabel.text
        amountLabel.text = tempText
        
    }
    
}
```

This is the way I use it.

```
lazy var balacnceView: BalanceCell = {
        let view = BalanceCell()
        return view
    }()
```

ANy help as to why the Togelbutton is not getting called is appritiatedswift

Comment: why you are using `cell` instead of `UIView` is there any reason ?

Comment: Because another  ViewController, I use this in the collectionView.

Comment: what i suggest you is to make it `UIView` and where you need to use collectionView .. add it to CollectionViewCell class contentView ... and where you didnot have collectionView use this UIView class directly ... this make sense ... adding collectionViewCell without collectionView is not a good design strategy

Comment: @jawadAli is right, you should do it, either you can try creating the instance of cell and use that instance to add target to that button and add function as the action which is in your ViewController not in BalanceCell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of `isUserInteractionEnabled` property is true in **UIButton**. You do not need to set this property to `true`.

However, the default value of `isUserInteractionEnabled` property is false in **UIImageView**. If you want to enable action in **UIImageView** *(or in subviews of UIImageView)*, then set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `true`.

In your code, you have put all subviews inside `bgImageView`. Just add this line of code:

```swift
bgImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled  = true
```